# Why dpkg -i can't find my Minecraft.deb file

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, software-center, deb, minecraft

I downloaded the Minecraft.deb file from minecraft.net and tried to install it first with the normal software installer GUI. What would happen is it would go from 0% to 100% really fast and then the install button would reappear as if nothing happened.

Then I tried the `dpkg -i` method using `sudo dpkg -i Minecraft.deb` but it gave me this error:

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'Minecraft.deb': No such file or directory.
```

Then I tried doing it with the path: `sudo dpkg -i /home/Downloads/Minecraft.deb`. Still didn't work. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the following error message:

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'Minecraft.deb': No such file or directory.
```

...because the path you typed to Minecraft.deb in incorrect. To show the correct path to Minecraft.deb drag the Minecraft.deb into the terminal or try using the following path instead.

```
/home/username/Downloads/Minecraft.deb
```

where instead of **username** replace it with your own username.

The correct commands would then be as follows:

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/ # replace username with your own username   
sudo dpkg -i /Minecraft.deb
```